# Python : Ensure string is exactly in A.B.C format .. ( two dots separating 3 strings )

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6

The problem with this code is..

```
 a = '1111.222.333'

 b = a.split('.')

 first = b[0]
 second = b[1]
 third = b[2]
```

is that.. if the string is missing pieces such as..

```
   a = '222.333'

the "second" can end up becoming "first"
```

i would like to ensure the string is..

```
 111.222.333
```

format. in other words has 2 dots seperating 3 strings

**UPDATE:**

first and second are always digits the last one is always 'test' the text..

in other words : 111.222.test

but perhaps this is for another question.

Comment: This sounds like a job for ... REGEX MAN! Da da daa, dadada daa :-)

Comment: can you say clearly what you want ? pls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution might be to use regex:

```
import re

a = '1111.222.333'

def does_string_match(a):
    return re.match('\d+\.\d+\.test', a) is not None

print does_string_match(a)  # returns True
```

The pattern `\d+\.\d+\.test` currently matches for:

```
\d+     1 or more numeric digits
\.      A literal period
\d+     1 or more numeric digits
\.      A literal period
test    The literal text 'test'
```

If the string is always in the format `num.num.test`, you could probably perform the test without using regex if you want. You could split the string by the period, check the length of the resulting list, then check each component independently. If the length is anything other than 3, or if any of the components are values you don't accept, then you know something went wrong.

```
def does_string_match(a):
    try:
        # If you can't unpack a.split into 3 pieces, Python throws a ValueError
        first, second, third = a.split('.') 

        # If you can't convert first or second to ints, Python throws a ValueError
        int(first)
        int(second)

        if third != 'test':
            return False
    except ValueError:
        return False

    return True
```

Comment: The split test he mentions could be: 3 == len([p for p in a.split('.') if p != ''])  *OR* 3 == len(filter(lambda x: x != '', a.split('.')))

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.split` with a `try`/`except` block, eg:

```
s = '1111.222.333'
try:
    first, second, third = s.split('.', 2)
except ValueError:
    # do something suitable
```

Here we only split twice on the `.` and if there's not enough arguments for the unpacking to work then a `ValueError` exception is thrown and you can then handle that appropriately, otherwise you have `first`, `second` and `third` assigned and ready to go.

Take out the second argument to `str.split()` if having more than three is not desired. The `except` block will then still run and you can handle it as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = '1111.222.333'
b = a.split('.')
if len(b) != 3:
    print('Houston we have a problem.')
else:
    try:
        int(b[0]), int(b[1])
    except ValueError:
        print('First two really should be digits!')
    first = b[0]
    second = b[1]
    third = b[2]
```

Note that this catches the cases both of too few and too many dots.